# Zoo Visitor: Display Member Fields After Registration, Before Logging In?

Tags: zoo-visitor, registration

When a new user registers for the site using Zoo Visitor, is it possible to grab any information from that profile and display it to the user before they complete the rest of the registration process (clicking link in confirmation email, logging in, etc.)?

For example, our registration template looks something like this:

```
{if last_segment == "success"}
   <h1>Thank You!</h1>
   p>In a moment, you'll receive an email from us with a link to activate your new account.</p>
{/if}
```

Is there a way to change `"Thank You"` to "`Thank You, {username}!"`?

Zoo Visitor's `{exp:zoo_visitor:details}` has parameters for selecting the user via different segments, etc., but, not sure how those might be used in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is safe enough just take the last record in DB:

1:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id as member_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = 1 ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1" parse="inward"}
        {exp:zoo_visitor:details member_entry_id="{member_entry_id}"}
            Thank You, {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}!
        {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{/exp:query}
```

2:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT username FROM exp_members ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1"}
        Thank You, {username}!
{/exp:query}
```

3:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:members limit="1"}
    Thank You, {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}! 
{/exp:zoo_visitor:members}
```

Comment: Clever, I like it!

Answer (score -1):

Does this work.

Thank you {exp:zoo_visitor:details}{visitor:username}{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}.

Comment: No; per my post, I'm not sure which of `{exp:zoo_visitor:details}` parameters might be used in order to achieve the desired results in this case.